# Accessing "internal variables" of list

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures, io

I created a subclass of list that writes to file every so often so that I can recover data even in the event of a catastrophic failure. However, I'm not sure I'm handling IO in the best way.

```
import cPickle

class IOlist(list):
    def __init__(self, filename, sentinel):
        list.__init__(self)
        self.filename = filename
    def save(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'wb') as ouf:
            cPickle.dump(list(self), ouf)
    def load(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'rb') as inf:
            lst = cPickle.load(inf)
        for item in lst:
            self.append(item)
```

Adding every object back into the list one-by-one after I read in the file feels wrong. Is there a better way to do this? I was hoping you could access the internals of a list object and do something like

```
    def load(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'rb') as inf:
            self.list_items = cPickle.load(inf)
```

Unfortunately `vars(list)` seems to show that list does not have a `__dict__` attribute and I don't know where else to look for where the items of a list are stored.

And I tried `self = cPickle.load(inf)` but that didn't work either.

Comment: The `list` object is coded in C, and you'd need to reach into a C struct to directly assign elements. You don't want to go there.

Comment: Are you sure you want to append the read items to the list? Don't you want to replace the existing contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to load the pickle directly into the list using

```
def load(self):
    with open(self.filename, 'rb') as inf:
        self[:] = cPickle.load(inf)
```

One other observation, if something goes wrong during the save, you might obliterate the latest persisted list, leaving no method of recovery. You would be better off using a separate file (perhaps using tempfile or similar, or just manage 2 files), and then replacing the previous file once you are certain that the list has successfully been persisted.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `extend()` to get your unpickled list loaded:

```
self.extend(cPickle.load(inf))
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually want to replace the entire contents of the current list with that of the loaded one. For that you can use slicing:

```
self[:] = lst
```